# Prove that the two functions of the derivative function is equal.

Tags: calculus

[1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyThe.gif) $g(x) = \int_0^x f(u)(x-u)\,du$

[2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns4Ny.gif) $h(x) = \int_0^x\left(\int_0^uf(t)\,dt\right)\,du$

Show that $h'(x)=g'(x)$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By computation:
$$
h(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^uf(t)dt du\\
\Rightarrow h'(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt
$$
by the FTC and replacing the argument of the function $F(u)=\int_0^uf(t)dt$ with x. Then for 
$$
g(x)=\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)du
$$
we use liebniz's rule, differentiating the integrand with respect to x to get:
$$
g'(x)=\int_0^xf(u)du+f(x)(x-x)=\int_0^xf(u)du
$$
Showing equality.